# Ajax conflict on category page?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have amasty layered navigation. Strange thing is when I click the product image on category page, amasty layered navigation ajax loader is invoked but I am directed to the product page and when click browser back button then I am unable to go back to the category page from where I came. I am using Ultimo theme on magento 1.9.2

Comment: Does the layered navigation extension update the URL when you are adding filters? It sounds like it is breaking the browser back button. That could happen if it is not registering the new urls when the ajax actions occur.

Comment: yes it does. sometimes it even the browser back button works. but the point is why is the layered nav ajax loader activated when I click the product image.